# TYPO3 sites config.yaml outsourced in own extension?

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, typo3-extensions, typo3-10.x

I searching for a Solution, how can i outsource the TYPO3 site config.yaml file in my own Extension?
thanks for help!

Comment: You can import other yaml files from an extension. Or use a symlink.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by doing import statements in the config.yaml of the site.

Like this in `config/sites/main/config.yaml`:

```
imports:
    - { resource: 'EXT:site_mysite/Configuration/Sites/my_site_config.yaml' }
```

In our cases a typical yaml configuration for the site looks like this:

```
imports:
    - { resource: 'EXT:site_myproject/Configuration/Sites/defaults.yaml' }
rootPageId: 401
... domains
... error handling
```

We move everything that does not contain a Page ID (root page ID; error handling) into the site extension, to make the site extension re-usable (= language configuration or route enhancers are moved to the site extension)